# Why does this evaluate to False?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit confused and can't explain this behaviour:

```
Vector3 k = new Vector3(Mathf.NegativeInfinity, Mathf.NegativeInfinity,Mathf.NegativeInfinity);
Debug.Log(k==k); // evaluates to False
```

though

```
Debug.Log(Mathf.Mathf.NegativeInfinity == Mathf.Mathf.NegativeInfinity)
// evaluates to True as expected
```

I'm using Unity Version 5.3.5f1.

Comment: Try looking inside the overloaded `==` operator with an IL browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html), `==` returns "true for vectors that are really close to being equal". However this implementation produces problems when the Vector is initialized with negative infinity for x,y,z.

Let's take a look at how `==` is defined for `Vector3`:

```
public static bool operator == (Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) {
    return Vector3.SqrMagnitude (lhs - rhs) < 9.999999E-11;
}
```

Before doing `SqrMagnitude`, it will first perform `lhs - rhs`, so let's see how `-` is defined:

```
public static Vector3 operator - (Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    return new Vector3 (a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
}
```

This is fine for normal numbers, however, since a.x, b.x...etc. are `Mathf.NegativeInfinity`, the subtraction will result in `NaN`. Now when it does `sqrMagnitude`:

```
public float sqrMagnitude {
    get {
        return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z;
    }
}
```

This will also return `NaN`.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664720(v=vs.71).aspx), we note the following:

> - If either operand is NaN, **the result is false for all operators** except !=, for which the result is true.

Therefore, when we go back to this code:

```
return Vector3.SqrMagnitude (lhs - rhs) < 9.999999E-11;
```

It simplifies to `return NaN < 9.999999E-11;` which will return `False` as stated in the docs.

---

Also, the reason why `Debug.Log(Mathf.Mathf.NegativeInfinity == Mathf.Mathf.NegativeInfinity)` behaves as expected is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664720(v=vs.71).aspx).

> - Negative and positive zeros are considered equal.
> - A negative infinity is considered less than all other values, **but equal to another negative infinity.**
> - A positive infinity is considered greater than all other values, but equal to another positive infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Equality operator can be or can't be implemented. It's just an implementation detail of a given type. Or it can be also *wrongly* implemented.

Even when all properties from a given class may equal when comparing two references, if `==` and `!=` aren't overloaded, or their implementation is wrong, it may end in unexpected results like yours.

For example:

```
public class A 
{
     public static operator bool ==(A left, A right) => false;
     public static operator bool !=(A left, A right) => false;
}

A a = new A();

bool equals = a == a; // false
bool notEquals = a != a // false
```

BTW:

```
bool referenceEquals = ReferenceEquals(a, a); // TRUE!
```

Comment: **"Equality operator can be or can't be implemented. It's just an implementation detail of a given type. Or it can be also wrongly implemented**" This is the problem. The `==` overload operator is implemented to test **approximate** equality.

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, after all, it's an implementation detail. OP thought that `==` means always "absolutely equal"

Answer (score 2):

As `Mathf.NegativeInfinity` is not an actual number. It is just a representation of `-Infinity`. According to [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.NegativeInfinity.html):

> A representation of negative infinity (Read Only).

Initialising a `Vector3` with `Mathf.NegativeInfinity` as x,y,z components will not work. If you try to print this vector you will get (-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity) instead of any numbers.

Running some tests show that `float.MaxValue` is the maximum value that behaves accordingly in `Vector3`.

And as Matías said in his answer about `=` operator. I believe that this is true for Vector3 class. Using `Equals` method will work as well.

here is sample code :

```
void Start () 
{
    Vector3 k = new Vector3(Mathf.NegativeInfinity, Mathf.NegativeInfinity,Mathf.NegativeInfinity);
    bool val = k==k;
    Debug.Log("Operator on Infinity Vector3: " + val);
    Debug.Log(k);
    Debug.Log("Equals Method on Infinity Vector3: " + k.Equals(k));

    val = (Mathf.NegativeInfinity == Mathf.NegativeInfinity);
    Debug.Log("Operator on float value: " + val);

    k = new Vector3(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue,float.MaxValue);

    val = k==k ;
    Debug.Log("Operator on float.MaxValue: " + val);
    Debug.Log(k);
    Debug.Log("Equals Method on float.MaxValue: " + k.Equals(k));

}
```

Above code gives this results:

> Operator on Infinity Vector3: False
>
> (-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity)
>
> Equals Method on Infinity Vector3: True
>
> Operator on float value: True
>
> Operator on float.MaxValue: True
>
> (340282300000000000000000000000000000000.0,
>    340282300000000000000000000000000000000.0, 340282300000000000000000000000000000000.0)
>
> Equals Method : on float.MaxValue: True